# Properties of Natural Log and Exponential from Derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to derive properties of natural log and exponential just from the derivative properties.

Let $f : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.
Without knowing or stating that $f = \ln(x)$ and $g = e^x$, but only knowing that $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $g'(x) = g(x)$ how do I show from just the derivative that:

- $f(xy) = f(x)+f(y)$ and $g(x+y) = g(x)g(y)$
- $f(x^y) = yf(x)$
- $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = -\infty$
- $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty}g(x) = 0$
- $g \circ f$ is an identity of $(0,\infty)$ and $f \circ g$ is an identity on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know how to do that in general, but using $\textbf{only}$ the derivative, I am a bit stuck, and would appreciate help. The text that inspired me to do this problem (I expanded it a bit), also expects me not to use integration.

Comment: It is not enough to know only the derivatives. For $f$, notice that $f(x) =\log(x) + c$ still satisfies $f'(x) = 1/x$. For $g$, notice that $g(x) = c\,e^x$ still satisfies $g'(x) = g(x)$.

Comment: Can you use power series?

Comment: You need to know that $f(1)=0,g(0)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These conditions can all be justified straight from the definitions your provided, with one caveat. We require knowledge of $f$ and $g$ at some initial point; as such, I will use $f(1)=0$ and $g(0)=1$. The steps are a little tricky, but only the first step is actually difficult, while the rest are mostly properties of inverses. That being said, this is a LONG problem.

**Step 1**: $g(x)>0$

We know that $g(0)>1$ by definition, so $g'(0)=1$ and $g$ is increasing at $0$. There is then some distance away from $0$ in which $g$ is increasing, since $g$ is continuous. Let $M=\sup\{x\geq 0|g(x)\mbox{ is increasing}\}$. Assuming $M$ is finite and since $g(0)=1$, $g(M)>1$, so $g'(M)>1$ and $g$ is increasing at $M$. Moreover, since $g'$ is continuous, $g$ must also be increasing after $M$, which contradicts the definition of $M$, so $g$ is increasing entirely after $0$.

A similar argument can be made to show that if $g$ was negative somewhere before $0$, it would be constantly decreasing, which cannot happen if $g(0)>0$. Thus, $g$ must be positive everywhere.

**Step 2**: $f\circ g$ is the identity map on $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $g(x)>0$, we may compose $f\circ g$. Differentiating this gives

$$(f\circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)=1$$

which means that $f(g(x))=x+C$ for some constant $C$. Substituting $x=0$ gives

$$f(g(0))=C\implies C=0$$

and so $f\circ g$ is the identity map on $\mathbb{R}$.

**Step 3**: $g\circ f$ is the identity map on $(0,\infty)$

We consider the derivative

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{g(f(x))}{x}=\frac{xg'(f(x))f'(x)-g(f(x))}{x^2}=0$$

As such, $g(f(x))=Cx$ for some constant $C$. Letting $x=1$ reveals $C=1$. We know know that $f$ and $g$ are complete inverses of each other.

**Step 4**: The limits of $f$ and $g$

Now that we know that $f$ and $g$ are inverses of each other and we know their domains, we know their ranges as well. This means that $g$ must output bijectively to $(0,\infty)$ and must always be increasing. Thus, $g(x)\to0$ as $x\to-\infty$ and $g(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$. Similarly, $f$ must output to all of $\mathbb{R}$ and is increasing as well, so $f(x)\to-\infty$ as $x\to0^+$ and $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

**Step 5**: $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$

We begin by taking a partial derivative of $f(xy)$ to get

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(xy)=yf'(xy)=\frac{1}{x}=f'(x)$$

In a roundabout way, the Mean Value Theorem states that $f(xy)-f(x)$ is a constant, as far as $x$ is concerned. This means that there is some function $h$ such that only depends on $y$ where $f(xy)=f(x)+h(y)$. Now, by taking the $y$ derivative, we have

$$h'(y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(xy)=xf'(xy)=\frac{1}{y}=f'(y)$$

This tells us that $f$ and $h$ only differ by a constant, so $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)+C$ for some constant $C$. If we let $y=1$, then $f(x)=f(x)+C$, so $C=0$ and we are done.

**Step 6**: $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$

Let $x$ and $y$ be any real numbers. Let $g(x)=a$ and $g(y)=b$, and since $f$ is the inverse of $g$, $f(a)=x$ and $f(b)=y$. This means that

$$g(x+y)=g(f(a)+f(b))=g(f(ab))=ab=g(x)g(y)$$

**Step 7** $f(x^y)=yf(x)$

We notice that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x^y)=f'(x^y)yx^{y-1}=\frac{y}{x}=yf'(x)$$

This tells us that

$$f(x^y)=yf(x)+h(y)$$

again, for am unknown function $h$. Letting $x=1$ and using the initial condition of $f$ gives $h(y)=0$, and so $f(x^y)=yf(x)$.

**Step 8**: $g(xy)=g(x)^y=g(y)^x$

We have

$$f(g(x)^y)=yf(g(x))=xy$$

Applying $g$ to both sides gives us $g(xy)=g(x)^y$. A similar argument can be made for $g(y)^x$.

There, all done!

Comment: Thank you for taking time to write out a detailed answer! This has been really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest part is showing $f \circ g$ is identity on $\mathbb{R}$ (assuming we already have the first bullet point). Since
$$(f\circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x) = g(x)/g(x) = 1,$$
we know that $f(g(x)) = x + c$ for some constant $c$. Then by the first bullet point,
$$f(g(2)) = f(g(1+1)) = f(g(1)g(1)) = f(g(1)) + f(g(1)) = 2f(g(1)).$$
One one hand, $f(g(2)) = 2 + c$, and on the other hand, $2f(g(1)) = 2(1+c) = 2+2c$. Hence $c = 0$, so $f(g(x)) = x$.